# C# Outlook Plugin Form Region

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-addin

I have added a Form Region to my plugin, so when you open a Contact, it will append the Form Region to the bottom of the contact screen.

This all seems to work fine when I debug the project, however I have also added an installer to the project. Everything seems to install correctly, however this Form Region will not show. It is definately the same version but I do not understand why the Form Region does not show when installing.

Any advice would be good, tried to catch errors, but cannot find anything, or even where I could trap the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in-case anyone see it I came up against this as well. Once you make your form region, Visual Studios will create the registry by itself when you debug it. In order for it show up when you install it you need to add the form to the registry for the deployment project similar to how you added the add-in to the registry.

Here is the [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206787%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for adding the forms to the registry and what the different Outlook fields are called. When I added mine the registry ended up looking like this:

```
▼ User/Machine Hive
    ▼ Software
        ▼ Microsoft
            ▼ Office
                ▼ Outlook
                    ▼ Addins
                         My Addin 2013
                    ▼ FormRegions
                        IPM.Note  -> MyAddin.MyRegion = "=My Addin 2013"
```

This is obviously only one answer to your question though, but this is what I needed to do to get them to show when I installed the add-in. Hope it helps anyone else.